# TypeError in freeze_graph tool while trying to freeze a graph in Tensorflow 1.3

Tags: tensorflow

I train a tf.contrib.learn estimator (specifically, DNNLinearCombineRegressor) in Python and save the model’s parameters and graph by specifying model_dir when defining the estimator. After training is done, I try to freeze the graph using the CLI as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223252/error-while-freezing-the-model-freeze-graph), and get this error:

TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("dnn/hiddenlayer_0/biases:0", shape=(10,), dtype=float32)

Any idea how to resolve this? Also how do I make sure that after training, when I use predict_scores() of the estimator for prediction, the frozen graph file is used to create the model? I want to freeze the graph so that predict_scores() doesnt reload the graph and its variables everytime for prediction. Thanks in advance.